# Php datetime convert to ISO 8601

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have an app that would call an Amazon api, the datetime requirements should be an ISO 8601 format. I tried the Carbon like

```
   'data_startTime' => 'nullable|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s',

   Carbon::parse($request->data_startTime)->toIso8601String()
```

The example data_startTime

```
  2019-12-10 20:11:24
```

Which resulted to

```
   2019-12-10T20:11:24+00:00
```

But per Amazon's requirement, it will just reject that param and will throw error
What Amazon required is the format should like this

```
    2019-12-10T20:11:24.000Z
```

How to achieve that using Carbon or any Php DateTime class ?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the DateTime class, select the time zone "Z" and generate the desired format with the method of the same name.

```
$start = '2019-12-10 20:11:24';

$strDate = date_create($start,new DateTimeZone('Z'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.ve');

echo $strDate;  //2019-12-10T20:11:24.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

If microsecond-precision is OK, `toJSON` might be the cleanest option:

```php
echo Carbon::parse('2019-12-10 20:11:24')->toJSON();
```

Note that if you already JSON encode the body you send, it will just be handled automatically:

```php
echo json_encode([
  'date' => Carbon::parse('2019-12-10 20:11:24')
]);
```